# Create own Gatsby Font-Theme

Tags: fonts, components, gatsby

I've finished part 3 of Gatsby tutorials (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/). Everything worked as expected.

This part of the tutorial was about a component that loads fonts.

Where can I find other themes or how can I create my own theme with my favorite fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my question myself.
I found other themes here. 
https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js/tree/master/packages

And based on the files in this directory, I can create my own theme.
../tutorial/03/hallo-welt/node_modules/typography-theme-fairy-gates